# How to remove the outermost array from this nested array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this nested array of associative array in php.

```
$input = array(array(
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 1", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 1"),
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 2", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 2")
));
```

I want to remove the outermost array such that it becomes;

```
$input = array(
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 1", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 1"),
   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 2", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 2")
);
```

I have tried this;

```
$new_arr = $input[0];
```

But it did not work. How can the outermost array be removed in php? Thank you very much.

Comment: That's the correct solution... what happened when you say "it did not work"?

Comment: It returned only the first record on the array.

Comment: It works: http://ideone.com/GLrOaN

Comment: To clarify, are you saying when you had the first array from your question, and you ran `$new_arr = $input[0]` then `$new_arr` contained `array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 1", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 1")`?

Comment: I made some careless mistake in my original code. Stupid me. Yes, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `foreach` like

```
$input = array(array(
                   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 1", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 1"),
                   array('title'=>"Dynamic Title 2", 'content'=>"Dynamic content 2")
         )); 
foreach($input as $temp) {
   $newArr = $temp;
}
print_r($newArr);
```

It also works as you have tried with `$input[0]`.